# Setup an MQTT Connection in Android

Tags: android, mqtt

I am totally new to using MQTT with Android, I am trying this code :

```
public class MQTTActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private HistoryAdapter mAdapter;
MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient;

final String serverUri = "tcp://iot.eclipse.org:1883";

String clientId = "ExampleAndroidClient";
final String subscriptionTopic = "exampleAndroidTopic";
final String publishTopic = "exampleAndroidPublishTopic";
final String publishMessage = "Hello World!";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            publishMessage();
        }
    });


    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.history_recycler_view);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(new ArrayList<String>());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    clientId = clientId + System.currentTimeMillis();

    mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(), serverUri, clientId);
    mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
        @Override
        public void connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String serverURI) {

            if (reconnect) {
                addToHistory("Reconnected to : " + serverURI);
                // Because Clean Session is true, we need to re-subscribe
                subscribeToTopic();
            } else {
                addToHistory("Connected to: " + serverURI);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
            addToHistory("The Connection was lost.");
        }

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
            addToHistory("Incoming message: " + new String(message.getPayload()));
        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

        }
    });

    MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
    mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
    mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(false);







    try {
        //addToHistory("Connecting to " + serverUri);
        mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                DisconnectedBufferOptions disconnectedBufferOptions = new DisconnectedBufferOptions();
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferEnabled(true);
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferSize(100);
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setPersistBuffer(false);
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setDeleteOldestMessages(false);
                mqttAndroidClient.setBufferOpts(disconnectedBufferOptions);
                subscribeToTopic();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                addToHistory("Failed to connect to: " + serverUri);
            }
        });


    } catch (MqttException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void addToHistory(String mainText){
    System.out.println("LOG: " + mainText);
    mAdapter.add(mainText);
    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), mainText, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void subscribeToTopic(){
    try {
        mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(subscriptionTopic, 0, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                addToHistory("Subscribed!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                addToHistory("Failed to subscribe");
            }
        });

        // THIS DOES NOT WORK!
        mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(subscriptionTopic, 0, new IMqttMessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                // message Arrived!
                System.out.println("Message: " + topic + " : " + new String(message.getPayload()));
            }
        });

    } catch (MqttException ex){
        System.err.println("Exception whilst subscribing");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void publishMessage(){

    try {
        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
        message.setPayload(publishMessage.getBytes());
        mqttAndroidClient.publish(publishTopic, message);
        addToHistory("Message Published");
        if(!mqttAndroidClient.isConnected()){
            addToHistory(mqttAndroidClient.getBufferedMessageCount() + " messages in buffer.");
        }
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        System.err.println("Error Publishing: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

I am getting this exception :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } in org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService$NetworkConnectionIntentReceiver@41c79f18
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:810)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:966)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:733)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10083 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1428)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1382)
at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock(IPowerManager.java:301)
at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked(PowerManager.java:746)
at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire(PowerManager.java:715)
at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService$NetworkConnectionIntentReceiver.onReceive(MqttService.java:821)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:800)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:966) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:733) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I already added the Network and the Internet Connection permessions.
I added the mqtt service to my manifest.

I can't seem to get where the code is going wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line from the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10083 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
```

You need to request the `WAKE_LOCK` in the manifest as well as the network access.

Comment: thank you, how stupid am I, I have seen the same question here with this same response.

Answer (score 2):

use this 
add permissions inside menifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and add inside application tag

```
<service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" >
        </service>
```

in the build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/"
    }
}

implementation('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

and use the code in your activity

```
String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
      client = new MqttAndroidClient(MainActivity.this, "tcp://broker.hivemq.com:1883",clientId);
        try {

            token = client.connect(options);
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("connect", "onSuccess");

                    publishmessage();
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("connect", "onFailure");
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with **MQTT** protocol but with something else that the app is doing...

It looks like you are trying to notify the user about something(new msgs perhaps)

in order to do that you need to declare the use permisions in the manifest of the android, in your case something like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```